# Segues Collection View inside TableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I've got a table view that inside that table view cell i putted a collection view, to make it look like pulse. 
It works fine but i need to push that view to another so i have to call a segue, that isn't in the class of the table view cell it's on the Main view controller.

```
ViewController *var = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[var performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toOtherView" sender:nil];
```

but Xcode is trowing this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver    (<ViewController: 0xc411b30>) has no segue with identifier 'toOtherView''
```

but the segue does exists.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: of course i know whats a segue, but i've got this problem

Comment: I don't think so. 
If you know what the segue is, then you'll know, that segue must have source and destination. And in your case you just created a new view controller and performed a segue, that your newly created vc doesn't know about it and not connected to it.

Comment: did you read that in my first view controller(lets call it VC) i have a table view, in the table view cell i've got a collection view. When you make customized table view cells you need a class, so i have that class (let's call it class tableViewCellClass). I've got the collection view that is connected to tableViewCellClass. the problem is that when the didSelect method of the collectionview activates i need to call the segue in VC

Comment: Well the solution is to leave the delegate of the CollectionView on VC and put the datasource of the CollectionView on tableViewCellClass